# Unable to display content query webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm running into an error with my CQWP on a page that has some very particular requirements.

I have a host named site-collection (subsite.domain.com) and the content query webpart sits on the default homepage of the site.  The site is anonymously accessible and pulls from a list that is part of a subsite (the permissions on the list are managed at the item level, so the subsite and the list are anonymously accessible, but not all the items in the list are).  The webpart works just fine if the user is logged in, however when an anonymous user visits the page they receive an error:

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID:d1e6a1ac-13f7-4b1c-a26f-bd1dc95f55dc

I've looked around the web, and the suggestions I've found indicate that I should use alternate access mapping to resolve the issue, but in my scenario I'm not sure how to configure this for a host-named site collection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the SharePoint ULS logs and look for that correlation ID (a unique ID generated for each and every request) - update your post with the exact error message. That will eithe